# Formula to determine # of values in range based on criteria in other column

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 columns of data. To simplify, one is based on favorite colour and the other is based on age.

[Click Here for Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmOGw.jpg)

I need a formula that will sum up the number of black entries for a specific age, and red entries. My actual data set is 4000 rows, so I need something that can do this on a big scale.
Hope this makes sense...

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using `SUMIFS`?

Answer (score 0):

So, if you wanted to count the `Red` entries at age `23`, assuming that **Colour** was in column A and **Age** was in column B, you could use:

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Red",B:B,23)`